Figuring out coordinates written as long numbers, no decimals
The label of these specimen tags says "NAD27 ConUS" which I know is the coordinate system, but this doesn't explain the coordinates which are written as "716935, 3474948".
The site is located in the Animas Mountains in the southwestern US, so it doesn't make sense that these would be decimal format without the decimal point.
There is no UTM zone noted so I don't know what to do to figure out what these numbers mean.
Any suggestions?

Easting and Northings (UTM  12 NAD27) 716935E. 3474948N is 31.390631, -108.719197 about here https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B023'26.3%22N+108%C2%B043'09.1%22W/@31.4647978,-108.8649958,11z/data=!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d31.390631!4d-108.719197!5m1!1e1?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTEyNC4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D

The conceptual piece you're missing is that coordinate systems have explicit units. https://epsg.io/26712 has units in metres. Not using a decimal point here just means that the recorded precision of the coordinate is the nearest metre, and not beyond that.

Using projfinder.com, and putting those coords in the X-Y box and zooming to the SW corner of New Mexico, I see nine possible coordinate systems very close together. Only one mentions "NAD27" though, and its  "EPSG:26712 Name:NAD27 / UTM zone 12N" so I suspect that's the one. Its a UTM Zone 12N but based on the old NAD27 datum.

